# Google Oauth - Where to sign in users, backend/frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, oauth

What is the difference between using Google OAuth and signing in users at the frontend of the application, and signing in users at the backend side of the application?

Example: Signing in users and getting the ID and a auth object in React or letting Node/Express handle everything, the prosess, redirecting and store it in a database.

Is there any advantages for one or the other methods, which are most common and are there any "rules"?

Answer (score 6):

> What is the difference between using Google OAuth and signing in users
>   at the frontend of the application, and signing in users at the
>   backend side of the application?

So to clarify to everyone reading this, signing in users at the backend side of the application is another way of saying OAuth for servers and signing in users at the frontend of the application is OAuth for JavaScript browser applications such as React.

Signing in users via OAuth for servers and browsers results in a 'token' that a server/browser can use to make requests on behalf of the user. We are asking the user to provide us access to their information via an outside service provider such as an email address, identification of some sort and it will be inside that token as well as some possible permissions that allow us to take actions on behalf of that user.

> Is there any advantages for one or the other methods, which are most
>   common and are there any "rules"?

Server-side OAuth is usually used when we have an app that needs to access user data when they are not logged in. So if you are attempting to build an application that needs to access the users email every ten minutes and possibly delete emails on the users' behalf, you would want to be able to access their email account every 10 minutes regardless of whether they are logged into our application. So for this use case we want to make use of Oauth for server.

Otherwise, if we are not trying to do anything on behalf of the user except sign them into our app, then we can just go with OAuth for browser.

Answer (score 0):

Those two things are very different. Without knowing the specifics of what you're trying to accomplish, you should know as a general rule that front-end-only authentication and authorization leaves you extremely vulnerable.

If someone knows JavaScript well, or is using editing plugins, or any of a million different things, they can bypass much front-end authorization. Or they could just watch to see what calls your app makes to the back end, then simulate those calls from something like Postman, bypassing your web front end entirely.

If you're not securing your backend, you're not secure. Typically systems do both.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a different ways of registering users to our website.

Signing in users at the frontend using OAuth can be very handy as it enables our users to not go through our boring forms in our website. Using OAuth is just one click away from registering users in our website. Beneficial to both the clients and developer.We are provided with the general information about clients by the provider(google,facebook) just clicking on one button.

Signing in users at the backend side is the traditional way of registering our clients. Here we force our client to fill the forms in our website(which may be painfull if it is a long form) and all the filled data is stored in our database.

So they are both different ways to register clients to our websites. Both are used very often. It depends on usecase and needs. Oauth can be used if you want to attract more clients by registering them just by one click.