# Google Sign In: Frontend or Backend? (React Native or NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, react-native, authentication, google-oauth, google-authentication

This might be a duplicate of [Google Oauth - Where to sign in users, backend/frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823611/google-oauth-where-to-sign-in-users-backend-frontend), but I would like this discussion to be more elaborate. I am developing both the backend and the frontend of an application and I would like to know where to integrate with Google.

According to some answers to the question, using the login on the frontend (React Native) is less secure, is this really valid? According to the most voted comment, it is a recommended alternative when you only want to use the login and nothing else.

When using some applications that make use of the login with Google I noticed that there are two possible "screens" of login. The first is similar to opening a page in the browser and when you want to add a new account on your Android device. That screen also shows the name of app as LINK, similar to google login using Firebase Auth.

[image]

The second shows the accounts that already exist on the device in the form of a popup. Some even show the application icon.

[image]

Thinking about "screens", what makes them different is the google login on the frontend or the backend? If not, how do I get my application to login in the form of a popup?

Comment: frontend, no real reason to do backend